# unable to Exchange authorization code with access token - Google Client PHP API

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client, google-api-client

I am facing very weird error, I have initially able to access token on development server, but when I moved that code on production server it automatically stop working. I have added production URL in my project console. Interesting part is that code is exact same. I can't see any error to fix this. Also When I am using 'offline access token' as type it still expire in 1 hour. Please help me with this. Here is my code

```
     //////////// Index.php

      $google_redirect_url = base_url('index2.php');
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig($this->google_credentials);
$client->setAccessType("offline");        // offline access
$client->setIncludeGrantedScopes(true);   // incremental auth
$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.business.manage');
$client->setRedirectUri($google_redirect_url);
$google_auth_url = $client->createAuthUrl();
```

Here is my code handler.

```
    //////////// Index2.php
     $client = new Google_Client();
     $client->setAuthConfig($this->google_credentials);
 $client->setAccessType("offline");
 $client->authenticate($_GET['code']);
 $access_token = $client->getAccessToken();
```